# Add column to table and fix value for existing records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I want to add a column called "payment_type" into my "orders" table.

Here is the migration that I have so far:

```
def change
  add_column :orders, :payment_type, :string
end
```

I want that payment_type to hold the value "normal" for all the records that currently are in the DB. However, not for the future records. I want no default value for future records. How can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you just want to set values for **all** existing records, you can use `update_all`, which is much faster than looping over all instances of order, as it uses just database statements and doesn't instanciate all the orders:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
end

def up
  add_column :orders, :payment_type, :string
  Order.reset_column_information
  Order.update_all(payment_type: 'normal')
end

def down
  remove_column :orders, :payment_type
end
```

`update_all` does not call any validations or triggers.

Comment: I'd recommend not using the main Order class, instead you should define a stub Order class within your migrations, otherwise the migrations will stop working in the future if the Order class no longer exists.

Comment: Even you can use change method in place of up and down mehtods. this above block will change to
    def change
      add_column :orders, :payment_type, :string
      Order.reset_column_information
      Order.update_all(payment_type: 'normal')
    end

Comment: sorry, I posted a wrong comment, `change` does work.

Comment: What are the consequences to omitting the `reset_column_information` step?

Comment: Well, Rails caches the column information for database tables. It atomatically creates accessors for these columns. To get access to new columns, your have to inform Rails that the columns changed. However in this particular case, `update_all` does not use accessors but generates pure SQL. So here you can skip it. Most of the time, your loop over existing records ... than you need it.

Comment: As @ShaunMcDonald already mentioned you should use a stubbed version of your Order class. 
    `class StubedOrders < ActiveRecord::Base
       self.table_name = 'orders'
    end`

And then in your actual migration like `StubbedOrders.update_all(...)`

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way to do it:

```
  class AddStateToSites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def up
        add_column :sites, :state, :string, default: :complete # sets default value for existed records
        change_column :sites, :state, :string, default: nil # changes default value for next
      end

      def down
        remove_column :sites, :state
      end
    end
```

And after that check it in console:

```
>> Site.last.state
  Site Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "sites".* FROM "sites" ORDER BY "sites"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "complete"
>> Site.new.state
=> nil
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def change
  add_column :orders, :payment_type, :string
  Order.all.each do |order|
    order.update_attributes(:payment_type => 'normal')
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know that you can do this in the `change` method, and don't have to write seperate up and down methods.

Comment: I know this is super old, but it's ill-advised to use ActiveRecord inside of migrations. Your models are up-to-date as soon as you clone, but during migrations, your database is in an older state. If some change occurred in the future where Order received a default_scope, this would fail to update all records (even though the default_scope wasn't there when the migration was created).

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned it is not good practice to rely on Classes that may be removed in the future, since it would brake the migration at that point.

Instead I use to execute raw mySQL directly:

```
execute "UPDATE `orders` SET `payment_type` = 'normal'"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to updated column stick with migration then above answers is awesome,
**But** if you want to update column locally on your own machine so that when you share code then others are unable to see the updated attribute, simple go to Rails console and loop...

```
orders = Order.all

 orders.each do |o|
   o.update_attribute(:payment_type, 'normal')
 end
```

**Rails 4**

Comment: also in console, use `Order.update_all(payment_type: 'normal')` unless you need validations (not very likely in this simple case). It is much faster, see above, and it's a one-liner.